# Is it possible to generate a network with any number of vertex such that every vertex has equal degree

Tags: probability, graph-theory, network

This definitely does not work for any number of vertex k and any number of degree n.
For example k=5 and n=3.

But how about other combinations?

Comment: If $2\nmid kn$ there are never any suitable networks: any edge has $2$ ends...

Comment: Cf. [Wikipedia](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_graph)

Comment: They give construction by circulant graphs, if the restricting conditions are met.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer here:
https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Handshaking_lemma
https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_graph
Thanks to Thomas Preu